# How to loop through SOAP Response in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have a CURL SOAP call in PHP, but I'm not sure how to loop throught the data.
I'm getting this response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:searchStudentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://..."><student><accountBlocked>false</accountGeblokkeerd><lastname>TestName</lastname>
...
```

How can I now for example show all lastnames?

When I add:

```
$students = simplexml_load_string($output);
```

And echo this, I get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }
```